# Advice needed to properly indexing a table with many fields to be searched on

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a user table that has many columns, it looks roughly like this:

```
dname:             { type: string(255), notnull: true }
email:             { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
email_code:        { type: string(255) }
email_confirmed:   { type: boolean, default: false }
profile_filled:    { type: boolean, default: false }
password:          { type: string(255), notnull: true }
image_id:          { type: integer }
gender:            { type: enum, values: [male, female] }
description:       { type: string }
dob:               { type: date }
height:            { type: integer(3) }
looks:             { type: enum, values: [thin, average, athletic, heavy] }
looking_for:       { type: enum, values: [marriage, dating, friends] }
looking_for_age1:  { type: integer }
looking_for_age2:  { type: integer }
color_hair:        { type: enum, values: [black, brown, blond, red] }
color_eyes:        { type: enum, values: [black, brown, blue, green, grey] }
marital_status:    { type: enum, values: [single, married, divorced, widowed] }
smokes:            { type: enum, values: [no, yes, sometimes] }
drinks:            { type: enum, values: [no, yes, sometimes] }
has_children:      { type: enum, values: [no, yes] }
wants_children:    { type: enum, values: [no, yes] }
education:         { type: enum, values: [school, college, university, masters, phd] }
occupation:        { type: enum, values: [no, yes] }
country_id:        { type: integer }
city_id:           { type: integer }
lastlogin_at:      { type: timestamp }
deleted_at:        { type: timestamp }
```

I have created a form that contains most of the fields (enums, country , city) which alows the user to generate a where statement based on the fields they selected. So if someone selected smokes: no and country_id: 7 then sql where statement could look like this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM user u 
WHERE u.deleted_t IS NULL AND u.profile_filled IS NOT NULL AND smokes = 'no' AND country_id = 7;
```

Because user could select any combination of fields to filter by, I'm not sure how I should go about indexing this table, should I just create a single column index on all fields that can be filtered? What would you advise?

Comment: Please, please tell me that your're using bind variables in your `real` query.

Comment: Any particular reason why: height, looking_for_age1, looking_for_age2, country_id are all signed integers (4 bytes). Can someone be -2147483648 ft tall or 2147483647 yrs old ?? Dont you think tinyint UNSIGNED would be OK for age and country_id (0..255 yrs old, 0..255 countries) height probably should be a decimal(3,2). Have you considered what happens when you have 2 million rows in the table and you need to extend an existing enum ??

Comment: @Gerrat, I haven't used bind variables, can you suggest a good read?

Comment: @f00, I will definitely need to review the column types and optimize them, I didn't think it was a big deal. Do you have any suggestions regarding indexing too?

Comment: @BugBusterX I don't really have a *good* read, but you could check out point #12 at: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/

Comment: @Gerrat, thanks for the info. I read all other tips too :) I am actually using prepared statements, since I'm using Doctrine ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a table at work with the same sort of thing, lots of columns and 1000 different ways to select. Its a nightmare. I did find however, there are certain combinations of filters that are used often. It is those I would create indexes for and leave the others which are rarely used to run slowly. In MSSQL, I can run a query to show me the most expensive queries that have been run against the database, mySQL should have a similar thing. Once I have them, I create an index that covers the columns to speed them up. Eventually, you'll have it 90 percent covered. I personally would never design a table like that again unless I had an AK47 pointed at me. (my indexes are 3 times larger than the data in the table which is very uncool if you need to add a bunch or records).
Im not sure how I would redesign the table though, My first thought would be to split the table into two, but that would add to headaches elsewhere.

User Table (UserID, Name)

```
1, Lisa
2, Jane
3, John
```

User Attribute Table(UserID, AttributeName,AttributeValue)

```
1, EYES, Brown
1, GENDER, Female
2, EYES, Blue
2, GENDER, Female
3  EYES, Blue
3, GENDER, Male
```

This would make identifying attributes faster, but make your queries not as straight forward to write.

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(*) as MatchingAttributes
FROM   UserAttributes 
WHERE  (UserAttributes.AttributeName = 'EYES' AND UserAttributes.AttributeValue = 'Blue') OR
       (UserAttributes.AttributeName = 'GENDER' AND UserAttributes.AttributeValue = 'Female')
```

This should return the following

```
UserID, MatchingAttributes
1, 1
2, 2
3, 1
```

All you need to do then is add a HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 to the query to select only the IDs that match. Its a bit more involved to select from, but it also gives a neat feature, Say you filter on 10 Attributes, and return all those that have 10 matching. Cool, but say none matched 100%. You could say hey, I found none that matched, but these had 9 out 10 or a 90% match. (just make sure, if I search for a blue eyed blonde female, I don't get a message saying that none where found but here are the next closest matching ones containing blue eyed blonde blokes with a matching score of 60%. That would be very uncool)

There are more things that would need consideration if you chose to split the table, like how do you store attributes as numbers,dates and text in a single column? Or are these separate tables, or columns. No easy answer either way wide table or split tables.

Comment: "blue eyed blonde blokes" would piss off a lot of users and make others question their sexuality LOL! That is an interesting approach though, I wonder if this would actually be faster.

Comment: Speed wise I cant really tell without testing it, but I would think it would be a tiny bit slower than hitting the current table with a index that fully covers your query. The difference being, it wont be any slower, compared to hitting your table without a covering index. Perhaps, you can add the split table in addition to your current table, and use it only for those kind of variable searches. You would not need to index the crap out of your user table, but you would need to keep both tables in sync which is not such a biggy. Dunno, its up to you on that one. Is it worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Each and every searchable field needs it own single column index. If your table is big and you do not have an index on the search condition, then every row will have to be scanned.

Adding a new user will be slower, but the way you describe your situation I would imagine your queries are going to mostly be selects with a few inserts.